# Python Windows10-64bit curses package " No module named '_curses' " already installed curses.whl

Tags: python-3.x, ncurses

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppcNi.png)

I have already installed the unofficial-curses as you can see, but why still "no module named _curses"?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. My python is in Conda environment.

[image: screenshot]

**And here is the solution:**

```py
anaconda search -t conda curses #to search for the available edition

conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/labscript-suite windows-curses #to install, the package above which is available for win64.
```